# Where to put socket.io server in WebStorm Express template

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, webstorm

I am trying to add socket.io into generated express server by WebStorm. Where I am supposted to setup server and run `socket.on` events? Just put them all inside /bin/www, or its messy and I am supposted to make some controller like index and users page have.

[image: My layout autogenerated by WebStorm]

PS: Also I have second fast question. Is dumb idea to have express Web server on same port as Socket.IO websocket server? I see, that all websites using subdomain to connect to socket.io, so they must be using different port.

Comment: What does WebStorm say?  Have you looked through the support/guides?

Comment: I fast got trough WebStorm guides and I cannot find some info about layout and what is proper way to use it

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a single answer to this. But to get some ideas of nice ways to do it, you could download some trusted examples. For example, [MEAN.JS](http://meanjs.org/) uses socket.io, and it is very structured. You may not need everything in the stack, but it's great for getting inspiration on organization. Best of luck!

Comment: I just want to be sure that before I start making some project I have everything structured by some non-written standards :) I am very new in full javascript website because I was using PHP and apache for 6 years. Thanks for answer

Comment: Hey, I totally understand. That's why I recommended something that's already set up like MEAN.JS. There's probably a pre-built stack out there that you could use/follow. But no one on here is really going to be able to give you clear directions because there aren't set standards as a whole.

Comment: Ok, so its like when you writing PHP app... You can use MVC pattern or you can just smash everything into one file and hope that noone will see it :D

Comment: Yeah, except for it's even more complicated because no one can agree on a proper pattern for web apps :D

Comment: Do you have some better experience with nodejs and javascript? Can I add you somehow If you have minute to help me with few mysteries? :D @Dallas

Comment: I'm still learning too -- not sure if there's a way to add people on here, actually.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158197/discussion-between-dallas-and-d3admau5).

Answer (score 0):

I get this post to life again because i was trying to make the same thing.

I tried something and it worked !

I just followed the Socket.io doc and tried to adapt it to this template.
https://socket.io/get-started/chat

Here's what i've wrote in my `www.js` from the template (didn't changed anything in this file).

```
/**
 * Create HTTP server. (This part was in by default)
 */

let server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Try Socket io integration (This is what i've done)
 */
let io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log("yeet");
});
```

and here's my layout.pug

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    script(src='/socket.io/socket.io.js')
  body
    block content
    script.
      let socket = io();
```

Now when I get my page, I get the log.

Hope it can help other people.